# Return one of two types of same typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I have the following type class

```
class MyClass c where
  aFunction :: c -> Bool
```

and two instances for two different data types

```
data MyDataType1 = MyDataType1

instance MyClass MyDataType1 where
  aFunction c = True

data MyDataType2 = MyDataType2

instance MyClass MyDataType2 where
  aFunction c = False
```

I want to write a function a function which takes two parameters of typeclass MyClass (which might be the same data type or might be different and returns one of them. I'm struggling to work out the type signature for this and I think I might be taking the wrong approach.

Would this be correct? If not what should I use instead?

```
chooseOne :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) => a -> b -> ?
chooseOne x y = if (aFunction x) then x else y
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving the type signature out and seeing if the compiler is able to infer one? Hint: why do you have to declare `a` and `b` as being separate instances of `MyClass` at all? Can functions return two types that might be different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your return value could be of either type, so the compiler will complain unless you use the same type for both, giving

```
chooseOne :: (MyClass a, MyClass a) => a -> a -> a
```

which isn't what you mean.

To combine two potentially different types into one, you can use the Either data type:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

so you would have

```
chooseOne :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) => a -> b -> Either a b
chooseOne x y = if (aFunction x) then Right x else Left y
```

But I'd rather write that

```
chooseOne :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) => a -> b -> Either a b
chooseOne x y | aFunction x = Right x 
              | otherwise   = Left y
```

Comment: "But I'd rather write that".  I'm a beginner, what is the reason for your preference?  I've been trying to notice when I can go with the first form rather than the second.  Should I stop that? Thanks.

Comment: It's just style rather than anything else. I like how guards make the condition clear. It feels more Haskellish to me, and I find it easier to read. However, I don't feel it's important; use whatever you prefer.

Comment: @AdrewC, I'm not particularly enamored of if statements, so I will stop trying to identify either or situations and just use guards.  Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd always associated Either with error messages, but this makes much more sense.

Answer (score 5):

The function you're writing is impossible in Haskell---the return type must be fixed and known at compile time. Thus, to write something like what you're interested in you need an `Either`.

```
chooseOne :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) => a -> b -> Either a b
chooseOne x y = if (aFunction x) then Left x else Right y
```

Eventually, even in dynamic languages, you'd have to have some code which handles both the `a` and `b` types identically. This "eliminates" the `Either` and is embodied in the function `Data.Either.either`

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
either f _ (Left a)  = f a
either _ g (Right b) = g b
```

For your particular case, since both `a` and `b` are instances of `MyClass`, it feels like we can make a slightly more convenient elimination function

```
eitherOfMyClass :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) => (a -> b) -> Either a a' -> b
eitherOfMyClass f (Left a)   = f a
eitherOfMyClass f (Right a') = f a'
```

But this actually won't type-check! If you look closely at the type you might be able to find the problem---the handler function we're passing in is specialized to `a` and thus cannot be applied to the `Right` side of your `Either` which is type `b`. We thus need to use `forall`, an extension enabled by `LANGUAGE RankNTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

eitherOfMyClass :: (MyClass a, MyClass b) =>
                   (forall x. MyClass x => (x -> c)) -> Either a b -> c
eitherOfMyClass f (Left a)  = f a
eitherOfMyClass f (Right b) = f b
```

This ensures that whatever function `f` you pass in to `eitherOfMyClass` is truly general to any instance of `MyClass` and thus can be applied to both the `a` and the `b` in your `Either`.

Comment: But if he has `f :: MyClass x => x -> c` then wouldn't it be far simpler for him to write `useOne x y = if aFunction x then f x else f y`? Then he wouldn't need RankNTypes, which is perhaps a little of a bit of a steep learning curve for someone who doesn't realise they could use Either.

Comment: Only if `f` is fixed. If you try to write `useOne f x y = if aFunction x then f x else f y` then you'll either need `RankNTypes` or it'll unify the types of `x` and `y` together. General elimination of an `Either` using a single function really requires `RankNTypes`... Though I agree that few use cases probably absolutely demand that at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

(See also [“Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass”](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).)

```
data MyType = MyType { aFunction :: Bool }

chooseOne :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
chooseOne x y = if aFunction x then x else y
```

Caveat: your real `MyClass` might not be simple enough to make this work.

n.b. If you could write it as a class in an OOP language, then you *can* use this technique. OOP constructors translate to free-standing functions that return a `MyType` value.

- All your class functions must take a class value as a parameter. So e.g. if your real class was `Monoid`, `mempty :: Monoid a => a` doesn't take a parameter so doesn't fit in this framework.
- Your class functions can't take multiple parameters that must be of the same underlying type. Again e.g. if your real class was `Monoid`, `mappend :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a` takes two parameters, and they may be of any type that implements `Monoid`, but they must both be the *same* type that implements `Monoid`; `mappend` doesn't fit in this framework either.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it *backwards*: instead of returning type `x` or type `y`, you could accept two functions as input and execute one or the other depending on what you wanted to "return":

```
chooseOne :: (x -> z) -> (y -> z) -> x -> y -> z
chooseOne f1 f2 x y = if aFunction x then f1 x else f2 y
```

Notice that if you do `chooseOne Left Right`, you now have the `Either`-based solution that some of the other guys have suggested. You could also do something like `chooseOne show show` to return a `String` as your result.

Whether this approach is better or worse depends on why you actually want to build this class in the first place (i.e., what your program is trying to do)...

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I am using different datatypes here as the data types will be written as a client using my library.